# Why is this entity relation constraint error showing?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I do :

```
var t = cboTrailer.SelectedItem as Trailer;
using (var db = new CAPSContainer())
{
   db.Attach(t);
   db.Trailers.DeleteObject(t);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This deletes a `trailer` object from the context and pushes those changes. But it fails and I get :

**Entities in 'CAPSContainer.Trailers' participate in the 'CustomerTrailer' relationship. 0 related 'Customer' were found. 1 'Customer' is expected.**

The issue is that the relationship between Customers and Trailers is like ---> `Customer 1-* Trailer` ... So if I delete the trailer it shouldnt be an issue.

So why the error?

**EDIT:**

I tried with both v4 and 4.4 dlls of EF. It seems if I attach the Customer first it all works, but closer inspection shows that even though no error occurs the trailer still remains.

```
var c = cboCustomer.SelectedItem as Customer;
var t = cboTrailer.SelectedItem as Trailer;

using (var db = new CAPSContainer())
{
    db.Attach(c);
    c.Trailers.Remove(t);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

PopulateTrailers();
```

--> still shows in list + even after app restart its still there...

EDIT 2:

This almost works :

```
            using (var db = new CAPSContainer())
            {
                db.Attach(c);
                db.Attach(t);
                c.Trailers.Remove(t);
                db.Trailers.DeleteObject(t);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

It gives (on 2nd delete) :

**An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.**

Its crazy that in the same project just before when I was using a single object context I did ..

`MyContext.DeleteObject(t)` and that was it. Now that same line is replaced with 5 lines and still there is an error.

Comment: Judging from the naming convention, likely a ComboBox.

Comment: yep combobox bound to an entity list of trailers.

Comment: it should delete it if your foreign key is defined correctly

Answer (score 2):

You may need to attach the customer that relates to the trailer you are deleting so that EF can remove the relationship as well.

## Edit

In addition to removing the trailer from the Customer, you need to delete it from the context as well.  Removing it from the customer only removes the relationship.

```
var c = cboCustomer.SelectedItem as Customer;
var t = cboTrailer.SelectedItem as Trailer;

using (var db = new CAPSContainer())
{
    db.Attach(c);
    c.Trailers.Remove(t);
            db.Trailers.DeleteObject(t);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

PopulateTrailers();
```

Comment: I seem to recall some oddities when removing child entities after attaching.  Apparently you have to explicitly remove them from the relationships in some cases.  I may have to go read up on it.  What version of EF are you using?

Comment: I havent found the article I was thinking I had read regarding this yet.  I suspect that it just has to do with updating the relationship.  I assume there is a property on Trailer that specifies the CustomerID?  Or is there a table that sits between the two that defines the relationship?

Comment: Yes there is a 'customer_id' field internally. EF / C# sees it as 'CustomerReference'

Comment: Alright.  See my edit.  Trailer must be removed from both context and Customer explicitly.

Comment: Strange, when I had a "singleton" context, I just did ctx.DeleteObject(t) and it never complained, now when I new up a new context and attach I have to go through all this...

Comment: Yeah, I have not had a whole lot of experience in detatched entities.  I would suggest writing some CRUDL methods or something to take care of this in a more reusable way and abstract it out.  So Trailer.Delete(db,trailer,customer) will attach the trailer, remove the relationship, delete the trailer and save changes all in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the source elements of the cboCustomer, do you include the Trailer?
like:

```cs
cboCustomer.Items = db.Customers.Include("Trailers").ToList();
```

and then delete the elements with:

```cs
using (var db = new CAPSContainer())
{
    db.Attach(c);
    c.Trailers.Remove(t);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```